# how to get multiple categories and subcategories for a product in a custom script in magento

Tags: php, magento

i'm trying to build a feed generator based on this post [Magento: Product data extraction for product feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956930/magento-product-data-extraction-for-product-feed). for the time beeing my problem is with the categories and subcategories of the product.
my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

define('SAVE_FEED_LOCATION','feed/compari.csv');

//$objDateTime = new DateTime('NOW');

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); //1 is set to select product in stock
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); //4 is set to select active products
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$prodIds=$products->getAllIds();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$counter = 0;
$feedaray=[];

foreach($prodIds as $productId) {
if (++$counter < 500000){

    $product->load($productId);

    $title_temp = $product->getName();
    if (strlen($title_temp) > 255){
        $title_temp = str_replace("Supply", "", $title_temp);
        $title_temp = str_replace("  ", " ", $title_temp);
    } //$title_temp will hold the product name

    $maincat = $subcats = '';
    $categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
```

if i do a var_dump($title_temp.' categorie: '.$categorie_id);

```
    foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){

        $categorie_id=$cat->getData()['entity_id'];
        $_cat_ac = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categorie_id);

        if($subcats_ac == ''){
            $maincat_ac = $subcats_ac = $_cat_ac->getName();
        }else {
            $subcats_ac .= ">".$_cat_ac->getName();
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($title_temp.' categorie: '.$categorie_id);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

i'm geting the corect result:

```
string(59) "product 1 categorie: 3" - prime    category
string(60) "product 1 categorie: 37" - sub category
string(45) "product 2 categorie: 4" - prime category
string(46) "product 2 categorie: 21" - sub category
```

further i need to prepare the data for exporting to csv, and i do it like this:

```
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);

    $product_data = array();
    $product_data['ProductID'] = $productId;
    $product_data['ProductName'] = substr(iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$title_temp), 0, 255);
    $product_data['SKUnumber'] = $product->getSku();
    $product_data['PrimaryCategory'] = $maincat_ac; //this is spitting same data for all products
    $product_data['SecondaryCategory'] = $subcats_ac;  //this is spitting same data for all products
    $product_data['ProductURL'] = $StoreURL.$product->getUrlPath(); //$StroeURL is set as a string
    $product_data['ProductImageURL'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();
    $product_data['ShortProductDescription'] = substr(iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$product->getDescription()), 0, 80)."...";
    $product_data['LongProductDescription'] = substr(iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$product->getDescription()), 0, 2000);
    $product_data['SalePrice'] = round($product->getFinalPrice(),2);
    $product_data['RetailPrice'] = round($product->getPrice(),2);
    $product_data['ManufacturerName'] =$product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
    $product_data['Quantity'] = round($stock->getQty(),2);
    $product_data['Currency'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

    foreach($product_data as $k=>$val){
        $bad=array('"',"\r\n","\n","\r","\t");
        $good=array(""," "," "," ","");
        $product_data[$k] = str_replace($bad,$good,$val);
    }

    $feedaray[]=$product_data;
    echo $counter  . " ";
 }
}
$handle=fopen(SAVE_FEED_LOCATION, 'w');
foreach ($feedaray as $fields) {
   fputcsv($handle, $fields);
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

the problem is with the maincat_ac and subcat_ac that are not displaing corect data.

Comment: i forgot to mention the version of magento is 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for the problem

```
$cats=[];
    foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
        $cats[]=$cat->getData()['entity_id'];
    }

    foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
        $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
        if($subcats == ''){
            $maincat = $subcats = $_cat->getName();
        }else {
            $subcats .= ">".$_cat->getName();
        }
    }
```

may be it isn't the best solution. if you have another idea please share.
regards